# How to fix socket_connect(): Host lookup failed [-10003]: Unknown server error?

Tags: php, rabbitmq

Cannot connect to rabbit.
It was working yesterday and it looks like it stopped working out of nowhere.

Tried restarting docker containers, includding rabbit.
Checked that rabbit container it is up.
Checked that rabbit interface is loading.
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that connections were wrong in the .env file. Copied correct connections from .env.example and it started working.

It was really unexpected, so I did not check this place instantly, since it was working yesterday and I did not change .env. So it means - need to check something what is not really making sense. Even after update it does not make sense how it was working yesterday if they were wrong and I do not know about any changes.